# Rails how to implement hierarchical associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

Is there a Rails way to implement hierarchical associations?

I'm currently trying to map below layout fields in database:

```
Product -> Product URL -> No Link
                       -> Internal  -> List (Select box) -> List Values
                       -> External  -> String
```

I could probably have `product_fields` table then try to use this with `type` field to determine the differences between list, tree and string types to map it to `product_list` or `product_tree` tables but I'm afraid if there are many type of relationships like this, it would be bad for the database query performance.

Is this the best way to go or are there any good known solutions for situations like this?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you want. Your current question is a bit abstract for me to understand.

Comment: Will you need to perform any kind of queries based on URL type? (like querying all urls of type "No Link"). If not, then I don't think you should take care of this in the DB. Just store a null, a url (string), or a comma separated urls (strings) in a field in the product and deal with the type in your code. I even think it would be more performance-efficient.

Comment: @TamerShlash thanks for this. That would be a good solution. How about using Ancestry `https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry` gem? Would this help? I just think it's good because I have a lot of fields like that. What do you think?

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper I've never used the ancestry gem and don't know how it works, and can't give any opinion/advice about it. You should probably add your question about it to the post above.

Comment: I have. The ancestry gem is for managing hierarchical structures, generally within the same model, though I have (gasp) implemented it with STI before (categories). I'm with @Chandranshu, you should provide details about your desired outcome and perhaps we can suggest a more fitting method? As it stands, I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DamienRoche desired outcome is the Product field where you can select Product URL types as radio boxes (above mentioned three) then once selected, it should come up with either a no value, select box or a text input box. So basically they are three level hierarchy system. I have a lot of these as field types to be implemented

Comment: What is wrong with a simple, nullable `product_url` column, where you dynamically present a select box of predefined urls (internal) or allow custom url (external)?

Comment: +1 for @DamienRoche. Your use case doesn't sound like needing hierarchical associations.

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper I'm not aware of the idea of hierarchical database structures, but your problem doesn't seem like a hierarchy, it's just a matter of "limited possible values" which, as I noted before, should be handled in the code rather than in the DB.

Comment: @DamienRoche I think you could be right. I might have to put those field logics inside the model.

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper I think that would be best. Try to implement it for a few similar fields and post another question or update this one if you run into further issues.